# Create Gallery Using FancyBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'd like to create a gallery where only one image is visible and when the user clicks that image, the fancy box gallery shows up. However, the fancy box arrows/exit button aren't showing up.

Here's my code:

HTML Header (I've downloaded the source code from their website), and all of them do load correctly when I click the links in the source code.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src = 'jquery-1.11.0.min.js'> </script>
<script type='text/javascript' src = 'jquery.fancybox.js'> </script>
<script type='text/javascript' src = 'jquery.fancybox.pack.js'> </script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='jquery.fancybox.css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src = 'jquery-scripts.js'> </script>
```

jQuery in jquery-scripts:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".gallery").fancybox();
 });
```

HTML of images:

```
  <a class="gallery" rel='g1' href="images/PastedGraphic-13.png"><img   src="images/PastedGraphic-13.png" width="200px" alt=""/></a>
  <div class = "hidden">
       <a class="gallery" rel='g1' href="images/PastedGraphic-2.png"><img src="images/PastedGraphic-2.png" alt=""/></a>

        <a class="gallery" rel='g1' href="images/PastedGraphic-1.png"><img src="images/PastedGraphic-1.png" alt=""/></a>
  </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Edit:
This is my directory. I just copied and pasted everything over.
[image]

Comment: So it's all working correctly but the fancybox controls aren't showing - is that correct? Might seem an obvious question, but did you include the fancybox images & sprites?

Comment: @markpsmith I added a picture of my directory. The sprite images are the ones that came in the source folder.

Comment: @markpsmith Firefox, I also have php script and I noticed another post someone had an issue with php. Could I send you the full page source? I'm really confused on what to do ;(

Comment: What would be useful is if you could create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for it.  If you're not familiar with jsfiddle, do a google search for 'jsfiddle fancybox' and see how others have set it up.  That way we can see what you can see.

Comment: @markpsmith Thank you for suggesting that, I forgot about jsfiddle. Here is the page http://jsfiddle.net/nhwY5/. I just used stock images from another example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem that has to do with the php code I have at the top of the script. When I remove the php code, it works just fine.
I'll be looking for how to run both the php and $(document).ready() function in the same script.